# Could you recommend a good shopping cart script?

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, mysql, shopping-cart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Ecommerce Script Should I Use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/which-ecommerce-script-should-i-use)

I'm looking for a PHP/MySQL script, free or not. Could you please recommend me one that can do the following:

The site I'm trying to build requires an extensive product catalogue, which will have around 600 products. Because there are so many products they will be uploaded using a CSV file or spreadsheet.

- Users must be logged in to see prices
- Users can add products to an order form, which they can then email to
  admin. (**NO payment processing whatsoever**)
- They will just add products to a cart, review the cart's content and
  click a button to send the order
- The order email to admin must have the order details attached in a
  CSV file.

**Newsletter**

Newsletter sign up. Admin can create and send newsletter from the admin section.

**User Login/Member Section**

After users sign up they can access their member section. In this section they can

- Edit their details
- See previous orders they have made, and click a button to send that
  order again

Comment: Please don't cross-post your questions. Post it in only one stackexchange site and if it needs to be moved elsewhere flag a moderator to move it for you.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about that. So, should I delete it here?

Comment: No. It belongs here. I flagged the dupe at superuser so the mods there can close and/or delete their's.

Comment: Why PHP/MySQL in your case? What is the reason for setting this tech constraint first ?

Comment: Because I would need to customize it a bit and I'm familiar with PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opencart.com should work well for you.  All those are configs you can set.  The only issue you will have is the attached csv file.  That would probably be something you would need coded.